# Paired but without connection

Tags: android, bluetooth

Im trying to connect a 2.2 android phone with a 4.1.2

It seems as if there's some problems though since my 2.2 phone says paired but not connected and when i try to run the method

```
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

On either device it crashes. Is there some problems with connecting a 2.2 phone with a 4.1.2 or?

Just tried and even a simple command like

```
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    boolean on = bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
```

Seems to crash at the second line even though the bluetoothadapter is assigned

Answer (score 0):

Found out i had not given the permission to use bluetooth so solved